# Codeigniter Session Configure Path issue

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to this framework and am having some issues
with it. I have spent some couple of hours googling. I went
to the CodeIgniter IRC channel to search for an answer but it's like
everyone was too busy to answer me.

Helping me here is the error code:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir(): Permission denied

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 136

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/application/core/My_Controller.php
Line: 11
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/application/controllers/Welcome.php
Line: 6
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Exception

Message: Session: Configured save path '/var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/application/session' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.

Filename: /var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 138

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/application/core/My_Controller.php
Line: 11
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/application/controllers/Welcome.php
Line: 6
Function: __construct

File: /var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: Module 'mysql' already loaded

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(0c3r9i4i6834ocdlreqk3upofrig52cs) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear)

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 170

Backtrace:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(0c3r9i4i6834ocdlreqk3upofrig52cs) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear)

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 172

Backtrace:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fopen(0c3r9i4i6834ocdlreqk3upofrig52cs): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 172

Backtrace:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Unknown: Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (0;660;/var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/phptmpdir)

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

I just lauch the site, but I don't really known how to fix it, here is the site link http://www.barklay.online/

Comment: "Message: mkdir(): Permission denied", seems the user does not have  permissions in the folder to create folders, on the other hand, please format the questions

Comment: Please include your session config which is in `application/config/config.php`

Answer (score 0):

The folder you have set for your sessions does not yet exist, and cannot be created by the user running PHP for your web server.

Run this to create the sessions folder

```
cd /var/www/vhosts/barklaynew/barklay.online/httpdocs/application/
mkdir sessions
```